# NameError: name 'Class' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

When I compile I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/dvdpd/Desktop/ProjectStage/Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Main:
  File "c:/Users/dvdpd/Desktop/ProjectStage/Main.py", line 6, in Main
    test = Reading()
NameError: name 'Reading' is not defined
```

Code:

```
class Main:
    print("Welcome.\n\n")
    test = Reading()
    print(test.openFile)


class Reading:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def openFile(self):
        f = open('c:/Users/dvdpd/Desktop/Example.txt')
        print(f.readline())
        f.close()
```

I can't use the class `Reading` and I don't know why.
`Main` and `Reading` are in the same file so I think I don't need an `import`.

Comment: EDIT: Thanks all and sorry for the stupid question!

Comment: You can also mark the question as deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declaration doesn't work in Python. So you'll get an error only if you create an object of the Main class as follows:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Welcome.\n\n")
        test = Reading()
        print(test.openFile)

# Main() # This will NOT work

class Reading:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def openFile(self):
        f = open('c:/Users/dvdpd/Desktop/Example.txt')
        print(f.readline())
        f.close()

# Main() # This WILL work
```

Answer (score 1):

Python source files are interpreted *top to bottom* by the interpreter.

So, when you call `Reading()` inside class `Main`, it does not exist yet. You need to swap the declarations to put `Reading` before `Main`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `Reading` before `Main`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `class Reading` before `class Main`.

```
class Reading:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def openFile(self):
        f = open('c:/Users/dvdpd/Desktop/Example.txt')
        print(f.readline())
        f.close()


class Main:
    print("Welcome.\n\n")
    test = Reading()
    print(test.openFile())
```